# How would I make 'arr' a function in order to use 'arr.sort' when not setting a pre-defined array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I want to create a function to find the lowest value within a set of numbers, but I do not wish to use the Math.min(); method. Below is my code I have constructed:

```
function min(arr) {
    var lowest = arr.sort((x, y) => x - y);
    return lowest[0];
}
```

but 'arr.sort' is not a function, as it has not been defined for obvious reasons: I want to be able to input *any* array into the 'min' function.

I tried creating a JavaScript function for finding the lowest value in an array of numbers, expecting to have a function that would accept any array and would output the lowest value in that array.

Comment: The real answer is **if you are getting the error *sort is not a function*, then you are not pushing in an array into the min method**. So the problem is not the code you provided. And your method mutates the original array, not sure if you actually want to sort your array. It is also very inefficient to find the min value, there are better ways

Comment: "*but 'arr.sort' is not a function, as it has not been defined for obvious reasons:*" it's only obvious that `arr` is not an array. It's not at all obvious *what* it is, *why* is it that and what should be done instead. You likely need to pass an array when calling `min`. But it's not really possible to know for certain with the code and details provided here.

Answer (score 1):

*I want to create a function to find the lowest value within a set of numbersfunction to find the lowest value within a set of numbers*

Just pop the sorted array

That is assuming you are calling your function with an actual array and you do not mind that array is modified

```js
const min = arr => arr.sort((a, b) => b - a).pop();


console.log(min([7,6,8,99,100]))
console.log(min([1000,999,998,997]))
const arr1 = [1000,999,998,997]
console.log("---------------")
console.log(arr1)
console.log(min(arr1))
console.log(arr1)
```

Comment: Doesn't work when called as `min("banana")` or `min({hello: "world"})` or who know what else OP calls it with.

Comment: `function to find the lowest value within a set of numbers,`

Comment: Right, and evidently that's not how OP calls the function or the code in the question wouldn't throw an error.

Comment: Hence the wording of my assumptions

Answer (score -2):

```
function min(arr) {
    arr.sort( (a, b) => a - b );
    return arr[0]
}
```

Pay attention, though, that sort() overwrites the original array.